# Service Broker activation procedure firing when queue is empty

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I'm sending a single message on a queue with an activation procedure that is intended to run continuously.  The procedure receives the message, ends the conversation and continues to execute as expected.  Meanwhile, new instances are being activated repeatedly and timing out on the receive (which makes sense, because the queue is empty) even though no additional messages are sent. What would cause the procedure to be activated without a send, and how do I prevent it?  Setting max_queue_readers to 1 is not an option, as I intend to send multiple messages once I get this issue resolved.

Comment: Is it possible that invocation one of the activation proc is sending a message to the same queue that it's activating on thereby creating a loop? The claim that the activation proc is firing when no additional messages are sent is an extraordinary one and, as such, requires extraordinary evidence. Have you used ssbdiagnose (or some other means) to verify that literally nothing is being enqueued? Lastly, what problem are you trying to solve? Having the activation proc do no work is not inherently a problem. It is weird if it's firing for no reason, but unlikely causing any issues.

Comment: No messages are being sent.  As mentioned the receive times out.  ssbdiagnose shows no conversations, while the proc is still being activated.  The problem I'm trying to solve is the procedure being called repeatedly, unnecessarily.  While it does not appeaar to be causing any other issues in my development environment, it does consume cpu.  To implement it in a production environment as a known bug would be sloppy.

Comment: The procedure is consistently firing 5 seconds after the previous receive times out, regardless of the receive timeout.  There was a 5 second waitfor in the procedure that's running continuously.  I thought this might be causing the activation, so I tried 6 seconds, it's still being activated every 5 + receive timeout seconds.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the activation procedure? I still suspect that it (or something else) is sending messages. Also, this just occurred to me - are you using [SB timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/begin-conversation-timer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in your system?

Comment: I can't post the entire activation procedure due to NDA, but I'll work on stripping it down to the bare minimum to recreate the issue.  Don't the facts that the receive always times out and the queue is empty indicate that there are no messages being sent?

Comment: Not necessarily. The way I've written activation procs in the past will loop until there's nothing left to do. Something like `while(1=1) begin waitfor(receive top(1000) from queue) timeout 15000; /* do something with received messages */`. Meaning that the proc will stay active so long as there are messages in the queue but will time out eventually. And that's by design!

Comment: By design, my activation procedure receives a single message and runs continuously.   Each message should launch a new instance of the procedure.  I'm currently testing by sending a single message.  If messages are being sent elsewhere as you claim, why would the receive time out and the queue be empty?

Comment: Ah! Your last comment sparked a memory in me. [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/service-broker/understanding-when-activation-occurs?view=sql-server-ver16) details when activation occurs. There is at least one unexpected condition in that list for me (i..e. a `receive` happening on the queue). Are any of these happening in your scenario?

Comment: There are receives happening (and timing out), only because the procedure is being activated unnecessarily.  If I'm interpreting this correctly, the procedure should not be activated if the queue is empty, which it is.  I'd like to create a bare-bones script to demonstrate the issue, but I'm under a time crunch at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This script will demonstrate the issue.  It'll run for 1+ minute to recreate the bad procedure activations.  I've recreated it in versions 15.0.2000.5 and 15.0.2095.3.  There is a single SEND, and the procedure is activated every 15 seconds.

```
create database bugaboo
go
alter database bugaboo set enable_broker
go
use bugaboo
go
create  table MessageLog (
        ID                  int identity not null ,
        MessageTime         datetime not null default getdate(),
        SPID                int not null,
        ProcName            sysname null,
        Handle              uniqueidentifier null,
        Action              varchar(8) null,
        MessageType         sysname null,
        Message             varbinary(max) null,
        constraint          PKMessageLog primary key (ID))
go
create  procedure spKeepRunning
as
        declare @Handle     uniqueidentifier,
                @Type       sysname,
                @Message    varbinary(max),
                @rowcount   int;
        waitfor(receive top (1)
                @Handle     = conversation_handle,
                @Type       = message_type_name,
                @Message    = message_body
                from        qBugaboo), timeout 7000;
        select  @rowcount = @@rowcount
                
        insert  into MessageLog (SPID, ProcName, Handle, Action, MessageType, Message) values (
                @@spid, 'spKeepRunning', @Handle, 'RECEIVE', @Type, @Message)
        if      @rowcount = 0
                return
        end     conversation @Handle
        select  @rowcount = 0
        while   @rowcount = 0
        begin
                select  @rowcount = count(*)
                        from    MessageLog
                        where   Action = 'STOP'
                if      @rowcount = 0
                        waitfor delay '00:00:08'
        end
go
create  procedure spResponse 
as
        declare @Handle     uniqueidentifier,
                @Type       sysname,
                @Message    varbinary(max),
                @rowcount   int;
        waitfor(receive top (1)
                @Handle     = conversation_handle,
                @Type       = message_type_name,
                @Message    = message_body
                from        qResponse), timeout 7000;
        insert  into MessageLog (SPID, ProcName, Handle, Action, MessageType, Message) values (
                @@spid, 'spResponse', @Handle, 'RECEIVE', @Type, @Message)
        if      @Handle is not null
                end     conversation @Handle
go
create  message type mtBugaboo validation = none;
create  contract coBugaboo (mtBugaboo sent by any);
create  queue qBugaboo with 
        status = on, retention = off, 
        activation (status = on, procedure_name = spKeepRunning, max_queue_readers = 8, execute as 'dbo');
create  service svBugaboo on queue qBugaboo (coBugaboo);
create  queue qResponse with 
        status = on, retention = off,
        activation (status = on, procedure_name = spResponse, max_queue_readers = 8, execute as 'dbo');
create  service svResponse on queue qResponse (coBugaboo);

declare @Handle     uniqueidentifier,
        @Message    varbinary(max),
        @dt         datetime
begin   dialog @Handle
        from service    svResponse
        to service      'svBugaboo'
        on contract     coBugaboo
        with encryption = off;
select  @Message = convert(varbinary(max), 'bugaboo');
send    on conversation @Handle message type mtBugaboo (@Message)
insert  into MessageLog (SPID, ProcName, Handle, Action, MessageType, Message) values (
        @@spid, 'n/a', @Handle, 'SEND', 'mtBugaboo', @Message)
select  @dt = dateadd(minute, 1, getdate())
while   getdate() < @dt
begin
        waitfor delay '00:00:13'
end
insert  into MessageLog (SPID, ProcName, Handle, Action, MessageType, Message) values (
        @@spid, 'n/a', @Handle, 'STOP', 'mtBugaboo', @Message)
waitfor delay '00:00:13'
select  datediff(millisecond, lag(MessageTime) over (partition by ProcName order by MessageTime), MessageTime) Dur, * 
        from MessageLog
        order by MessageTime
```